# How to clean a dataset having intervals number values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, data-cleaning

I have a dataset containing a series of temperatures measurements like:

my question is: how can I convert this series into a new series containing only the maximum value if it's an interval and the same value if not.
thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can split values by separator, convert to floats and get maximal values:

```
df['max'] = df['temperatue'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(float).max(axis=1)
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.strip(), errors='coerce')
df['max'] = df['temperatue'].str.split('-', expand=True).apply(f).max(axis=1)
```

Comment: hello i did the same thing for the temperature value : max['TEMP'] =df['Temperature (oC)'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(float).max(axis=1) , but i get this error message : ValueError: could not convert string to float why?  and thanks for your answers

Comment: @Developperzaid - Can you check edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Series.apply` with `map` and `string.split`:

```
In [1186]: df['maxval'] = df.temperatue.apply(lambda x: max(map(float, x.split('-'))))

In [1200]: df
Out[1200]: 
  temperatue  maxval
0     3.5-10    10.0
1          7     7.0
2      10-15    15.0
3        NAN     NaN
4   20.5-111   111.0
```

Comment: @jezrael Is it fine now?

Comment: @Developperzaid Can you try my answer?

Comment: Okey i will try both of them, thanks

Comment: Mayank Porwal: thanks for your answer but i get this error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Temperature Jezreel : your code works fine thank you so much.